# Update div on typing base on data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to have text preview to display the example layout of a page. So when I put the title it's text will show in the title div base on the `data-target` value. Meaning I have multiple inputs to do.

So I write code but it's somehow not send the preview text to the desired div. I'm not good in jquery nor english, sorry.

**HTML**

```
<div id="h1"></div>
<div id="h2"></div>
<hr />

<input type="text" onkeypress="livePreview(this.value);" data-target="h1" placeholder="h1 value" />
<input type="text" onkeypress="livePreview(this.value);" data-target="h2" placeholder="h2 value" />
```

**Javascript**

```
        var timerHandle = false; // global!
        function livePreview(what) {
          $('div').data('target').html(what);//use target to display in div
          if (timerHandle) clearTimeout(timerHandle);
          timerHandle = setTimeout(sendItOff, 500); // delay is in milliseconds
        }

        function sendItOff() {
          what = document.getElementsByClassName("live").value;
          console.log("Sending " + what);
        }
```

This is the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ue2aysdq/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event should be `keyup`

https://jsfiddle.net/tejashsoni111/ue2aysdq/7/

```
jQuery('input[type="text"]').on('keyup', function(){
    var id = "#"+jQuery(this).data('target');
    jQuery(id).html(jQuery(this).val());
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Use keyup event bind it to the input field if you want a live preview:

```
        $('input[data-target]').keyup(function() {
          var el = '#' + $(this).attr('data-target');//build the id for the preview element
          $(el).text($(this).val());//change the elements text with the value of the input field
        });
```

demo:https://jsfiddle.net/ue2aysdq/11/

Comment: the text is not live, need a space to show the last letter.

Answer (score 0):

I simply apply with target into function event.

```js
var timerHandle = false; // global!
 function livePreview(what,target) {
    $('#'+target).html(what);
  }

   function sendItOff() {
     what = document.getElementsByClassName("live").value;
     console.log("Sending " + what);
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="h1"></div>
    <div id="h2"></div>
    <hr />
    
    <input type="text" onkeypress="livePreview(this.value,'h1');"placeholder="h1 value" />
    <input type="text" onkeypress="livePreview(this.value,'h2');"  placeholder="h2 value" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use JQuery to do this:
https://jsfiddle.net/ue2aysdq/9/

```
<div id="h1"></div>
<div id="h2"></div>
<hr />

<input type="text" data-target="h1" placeholder="h1 value" id="h1in"/>
<input type="text" data-target="h2" placeholder="h2 value" id="h2in"/>


$('#h1in').keyup(function () {
    var impt = $(this).val();
    $("#h1").html(impt);
});

$('#h2in').keyup(function () {
    var impt = $(this).val();
    $("#h2").html(impt);
});
```

Comment: I have nearly 10 inputs to do :(